# How to add a feature class from a geodatabase to QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Banging my head against the wall on this one:
I've tried this method:
([Adding feature class within file geodatabase in QGIS with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311335/adding-feature-class-within-file-geodatabase-in-qgis-with-python))

```
uri = "C:/Temp/my.gdb|layername=fcName" 
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer_name_you_like", "ogr") 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Adding it as a default value does work as long as QgsProject is included:

```
       self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon],
                defaultValue=r'C:/Data/7A_Mapping/BaseData/7A_Mapping.gdb|layername = LGA_POLYGON',
            )
        )
```

Note that I can browse to the geodatabase and add the feature layer with no issues, I just can't get it to open the layer through PyQGIS

I'm using QGIS version 3.22.13-Białowieża
and

```
import os
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import (Qgis,
                       QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProject,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsVectorLayer,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingParameterEnum,
                       QgsMessageLog)
                       
from qgis import processing
```

Comment: Can't understand. Are you trying to  add layer to the project or use it as a parameter in algorythm?

Comment: I can't do either and I'm wondering if there is something fundamental I have missed about adding Geodatabase Data to QGIS which would explain both.
Ideally I would prefer to add it via the first method.

Comment: I've managed to do it via adding it as a default value to the input but I would prefer to add it via QgsVectorLayer as this will cause my users much less confusion about what data to add and from where

Answer (score 1):

Add the layer manually and

```
src = iface.activeLayer().source() #Add the layer 
print(src)
```

To see what syntax it expects. This is working for me:

```
fgdb = r'C:/GIS/data/mydatabase.gdb'
layername = 'points123'
src = f"{fgdb}|layername={layername}"
vl = QgsVectorLayer(src, "myLayer", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Thankyou! I suspect using src = f"{fgdb}|layername={layername}"  is the key, python strings aren't my strong point.

Comment: Nice! I think what you are doing should also work, dont know why it doesnt

Comment: Yep - I ended up defining the Geodatabase path and filename using os.path.join() and then joining the two using src as you have shown.